# css not showing correctly asp.net mvc

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

hi i'm  working on a admin template. I converted the html codes into mvc structure. Now i am stuck , when i create a page using the layout in the shared folder the footer goes up to the navigation bar. for more understanding check the screenshot [image]

[image]

[image]

here is my _layoutadmin.cshtml

```
   <div class="container body">

    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
            <div class="left_col scroll-view">
                <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
                    <a href="index.html" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>Admin Panel</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <!-- menu prile quick info -->
                <div class="profile">
                    <div class="profile_pic">
                        <img src="~/Content/admin/AdminLogo.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img"/>
                        @*<img src="images/img.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">*@
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile_info">
                        <span>Welcome,</span>
                        <h2>John Doe</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /menu prile quick info -->
                <br />
                <!-- sidebar menu -->
                <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
                    <div class="menu_section">
                        <h3>General</h3>
                        <ul class="nav side-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="index2.html">Dashboard2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="index3.html">Dashboard3</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="form.html">General Form</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="form_advanced.html">Advanced Components</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="form_validation.html">Form Validation</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="form_wizards.html">Form Wizard</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="form_upload.html">Form Upload</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="form_buttons.html">Form Buttons</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> UI Elements <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="general_elements.html">General Elements</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="media_gallery.html">Media Gallery</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="icons.html">Icons</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="glyphicons.html">Glyphicons</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="widgets.html">Widgets</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="invoice.html">Invoice</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="inbox.html">Inbox</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="calender.html">Calender</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Tables <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="tables.html">Tables</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="tables_dynamic.html">Table Dynamic</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Data Presentation <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="chartjs.html">Chart JS</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="chartjs2.html">Chart JS2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="morisjs.html">Moris JS</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="echarts.html">ECharts </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="other_charts.html">Other Charts </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu_section">
                        <h3>Live On</h3>
                        <ul class="nav side-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Additional Pages <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="e_commerce.html">E-commerce</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="project_detail.html">Project Detail</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="profile.html">Profile</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Extras <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="page_404.html">404 Error</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="page_500.html">500 Error</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="plain_page.html">Plain Page</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="pricing_tables.html">Pricing Tables</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Landing Page <span class="label label-success pull-right">Coming Soon</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /sidebar menu -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- top navigation -->
        <div class="top_nav">
            <div class="nav_menu">
                <nav class="" role="navigation">
                    <div class="nav toggle">
                        <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="">John Doe
                                <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu animated fadeInDown pull-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;">  Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;">
                                        <span class="badge bg-red pull-right">50%</span>
                                        <span>Settings</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;">Help</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /top navigation -->
        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">
            <!-- top tiles -->
            @RenderBody()

            <!-- footer content -->
            <footer>
                <div class="copyright-info">
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        Gentelella - Bootstrap Admin Template by <a href="https://colorlib.com">Colorlib</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </footer>
            <!-- /footer content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="custom_notifications" class="custom-notifications dsp_none">
    <ul class="list-unstyled notifications clearfix" data-tabbed_notifications="notif-group"></ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="notif-group" class="tabbed_notifications"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your CSS files? Or else, you can inspect the element and its css properties in the developer tools of a browser

Comment: its a admin template it contains the bootstrap css

Comment: share your cshtml file to find the problem

Comment: layout.cshtml or the page i created using the layout

Comment: Have you tried moving the footer out to parent div of right_Col div??

Comment: ya but didn't worked @Sujith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<footer>` tag in HTML does not create a sticky bottom footer.
Have a look to this [Bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)